# Protobuf-net serialization error = "The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated"

Tags: protobuf-net

The following scenario seems to cause the exception in Protobuf.net on deserialization.  Have I done something wrong?  Is there a way round this?

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Ant))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Cat))]
public interface IBeast
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Ant : IBeast
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Cat : IBeast
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(AntRule1))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(AntRule2))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(CatRule1))]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(CatRule2))]
public interface IRule<T> where T : IBeast
{
    bool IsHappy(T beast);
}

[ProtoContract]
public class AntRule1 : IRule<Ant>
{
    public bool IsHappy(IAnt beast)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class AntRule2 : IRule<Ant>
{
    public bool IsHappy(IAnt beast)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class CatRule1 : IRule<Cat>
{
    public bool IsHappy(ICat beast)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class CatRule2 : IRule<Cat>
{
    public bool IsHappy(ICat beast)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class TestSerialization
{
    public void Serialize()
    {
        var antRules = new List<IRule<Ant>>();
        antRules.Add(new AntRule1());
        antRules.Add(new AntRule2());

        var catRules = new List<IRule<Cat>>();
        catRules.Add(new CatRule1());
        catRules.Add(new CatRule2());

        using (var fs = File.Create(@"c:\temp\antRules.bin"))
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, antRules);

            fs.Close();
        }

        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp\antRules.bin"))
        {
            List<IRule<Ant>> list;
            list = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<IRule<Ant>>>(fs);

            fs.Close();
        }

        using (var fs = File.Create(@"c:\temp\catRules.bin"))
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fs, catRules);

            fs.Close();
        }

        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp\catRules.bin"))
        {
            List<IRule<Cat>> list;
            list = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<IRule<Cat>>>(fs);

            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to look, but I'm having difficulty getting your sample to compile; after adding the missing `ICat`/`IAnt` there are still a number of build fails. If I monkey with it too much, I don't know that I am looking at the same problem... can you post an example that compiles?

Comment: Actually, I *think* I have the repro... looking

Comment: ah, sorry, I must have lost something during my editing and cutting and pasting.  Let me know if you need me to copy the code over again.

Comment: Sorry - IAnt and ICat should not exist.  The rules should be like this...  public class AntRule1 : IRule<Ant>

Comment: I *think* I got enough to post an answer - let me know either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately I suspect the issue here is:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(1, typeof(AntRule1))]
    [ProtoInclude(2, typeof(AntRule2))]
    [ProtoInclude(3, typeof(CatRule1))]
    [ProtoInclude(4, typeof(CatRule2))]
    public interface IRule<T> where T : IBeast
```

This says that *for any `T`*, `IRule<T>` has 4 children. This has the side effect of saying *if* you have more than one `T`, each of `AndRule1`...`CatRule2` each have "n" parents, which isn't good. Let's instead assume that `IRule<Ant>` has 2 ant-rules, and so on... (after all, I doubt that `CatRule1` is really an implementation of `IRule<Ant>`). Currently this can only be expressed via `RuntimeTypeModel`, since the attributes would always apply for *all* `T`:

```
[ProtoContract]
public interface IRule<T> where T : IBeast
```

and

```
// note these are unrelated networks, so we can use the same field-numbers
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(IRule<Ant>)]
    .AddSubType(1, typeof(AntRule1)).AddSubType(2, typeof(AntRule2));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(IRule<Cat>)]
    .AddSubType(1, typeof(CatRule1)).AddSubType(2, typeof(CatRule2));
```

and then it works. Note the configuration only needs to be done once, usually at app-startup.

---

Thinking about it, I could *probably* just test at runtime, and in the case of generics simply ignore any that don't apply - by which I mean when evaluating `IRule<Dog>`, only consider the specific types if they *implement* `IRule<Dog>`. I'm still in two minds, though.

Comment: Another quick and accurate response.  That has worked well.  Many thanks again.

Comment: @MarcGravell When using the `RuntimeTypeModel` do you also have to use the `[ProtoContract]` attribute (and will using the attribute if not needed break anything)?