# protobuf-net throwing exception for generic base class

Tags: protobuf-net

I have the following..

```
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(50, typeof(DateRange)), ProtoInclude(51, typeof(IntRange))]
public class Range<T> : IEquatable<Range<T>>, IEquatable<OpenRange<T>> where T: struct, IComparable<T>
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public T Start { get; set; }
   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public T End { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DateRange : Range<DateTime>
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class IntRange : Range<int>
{
}
```

When I try to serialize a DateRange I get the following error..

ProtoBuf.ProtoException : A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy (DateRange)
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy

After spending some time in the source code I am pretty sure the problem is that DateRange and IntRange both techincally have a different parent since Range< DateTime> != Range< int>.  So really I am not sure how we`re expected to handle generics.

Comment: I think this is the identical problem to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333233/protobuf-net-serialization-error-the-type-cannot-be-changed-once-a-serializer - can you check and let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ênded up taking the details from the issue Marc linked to and created this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (Range<DateTime>)]
   .AddSubType(50, typeof (DateRange));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Range<int>)]
   .AddSubType(50, typeof(IntRange));
```

Kind of a pain but at least it works!

Comment: Cool - I'll see what I can do to infer that, seeing as it keeps coming up

Comment: Documentation would do it for me.. I couldn not find anything on ProtoInclude other then what was on here :)